# How to check a value in Firebase Database before update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code to update Question score in Firebase Database:

**Code for sending score to Firebase:**

```
setAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {
                        String username = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                        //Upload points to Database
                        question_score.child(String.format("%s_%s", username,
                                Common.categoryID))
                                .setValue(new QuestionScore(String.format("%s_%s", username,
                                        Common.categoryID),
                                        username,
                                        String.valueOf(score),
                                        Common.categoryID,
                                        Common.categoryName));

                    }


                    // Log.d(LOGIN_STATUS_CHANGED_TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());


                    else {
                        //  Log.d(LOGIN_STATUS_CHANGED_TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                        // close the game room
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

**Questions Score Model**

```
public QuestionScore(String question_Score, String user, String score, String categoryID, String categoryName) {
        Question_Score = question_Score;
        this.user = user;
        this.score = score;
        CategoryID = categoryID;
        CategoryName = categoryName;
    }
```

**And Firebase json:**

```
"Smrodo_01" : {
      "categoryID" : "01",
      "categoryName" : "Intelligence",
      "question_Score" : "Smrodo_01",
      "score" : "30",
      "user" : "Smrodo"
    },
```

How can i check the value of existing score and update only if new score is higher than the existing?

Comment if any clarification is needed.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  Are you saying you don't know how to read a value out of the database?  There is documentation for reading and writing data in Realtime Database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: @DougStevenson I need a specific value, the score of auth user in category ID and make the comparison. And yes its hard for me as i m not a professional programer.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that shows how you check for a specific value. Please add it to your question.